# Downloading file

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem 
**here is my script for downloading a file but i receive "invalid request" message**.............................................. why???

```
$file = 'var/www/html/share/files/'.$_GET['filename'];

if (is_readable ($file)) {
$fsize = $row[size];
$path_parts = pathinfo($file);
$ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
$ctype="video/".$ext;
    header("Content-type: ".$ctype); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");  
 header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
    readfile($file);
exit;
} else {
        die("Invalid request");
      }
```

Comment: Is that formatting and are those `.`s really necessary?

Comment: This is the best code to ask applicants for 'how much bad practice can be put into 35 lines of code'

Answer (score 3):

You receive that message because the code you wrote displays that message.

Apparently, this results in a `false` value:

```
if (is_readable ($file))
```

You're setting the value of `$file` here:

```
$file = 'var/www/html/share/files/'.$_GET['filename'];
```

It's very likely that you meant to prepend that with a root folder:

```
$file = '/var/www/html/share/files/'.$_GET['filename'];
```

Otherwise you're looking for the file in a folder called `var` *relative to the current folder*, which is unlikely.

Also, note that what you're doing is *very* bad practice.  With this code any user can request any file from your computer.  For example, what if `filename` in the GET request is this:

```
../../../../../etc/passwd
```

Comment: BIG THAAAAAAAAANKS .. it worked ... and for security i have further adds ..thanks again :)

Comment: @rose: And for your "further adds" I have further doubts, given the limited code you're shown so far.  (You also have SQL injection vulnerabilities, etc.)  Seriously, I can't stress this enough.  Allowing users to request any file from your computer is a *bad idea*.  Every developer has had this idea, myself included many years ago.  It works fine, until somebody exploits it.  It shouldn't be done in the first place.